# Updated d3v4 fiddle not working

Tags: d3.js

I am upgrading this [d3v3 pie chart code](http://bl.ocks.org/juan-cb/1984c7f2b446fffeedde) into d3v4 pie chart. But it is not working. Any insight would be highly appreciated.
[v4 fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3z433eym/4/)
The code is pretty much the same apart from these few changes i have made:

```
var pie = d3.pie()
var arc = d3.arc()
var outerarc = d3.arc()
```

Comment: It **is** working, you just forgot to reference v4 in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1L823cgv/ Btw, there is no `schemeCategory20`, the correct is `d3.schemeCategory20`.

Comment: Hey! i had attached the wrong fiddle by mistake. Could you look into the updated and suggst again?

Comment: I just wrote an answer. Someone voted to close the question as a typo, because your first fiddle had, indeed, just a typo, and the question should be closed. But you edited the question providing another fiddle, and the question here is an entirely different one. Thus, if you want, edit your question to make this clear and avoid more *"close as typographical error"* votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In D3 v4.x, there is no more the *magic* of the `enter().append`, which changes the update selection in v3.x.

Now, you have to `merge` the selections:

```
//here you bind the data. This is the "update" selection
var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
    .data(pie(data), key);

//now comes your enter selection
slice.enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "slice")
    .merge(slice)//from now on, "enter" + "update" selections
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.data.label);
    })
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
        this._current = this._current || d;
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        this._current = interpolate(0);
        return function(t) {
            return arc(interpolate(t));
        };
    })
```

Here is your code with the merged selections:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .append("g")

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "lines");

var width = 960,
  height = 450,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var arc = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.4);

var outerArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var key = function(d) {
  return d.data.label;
};

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing", "elit", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", "tempor", "incididunt"])
  .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

function randomData() {
  var labels = color.domain();
  return labels.map(function(label) {
    return {
      label: label,
      value: Math.random()
    }
  });
}

change(randomData());

d3.select("button")
  .on("click", function() {
    change(randomData());
  });


function change(data) {

  /* ------- PIE SLICES -------*/
  var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
    .data(pie(data), key);

  slice.enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "slice")
    .merge(slice)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.data.label);
    })
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        return arc(interpolate(t));
      };
    })

  slice.exit()
    .remove();

  /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/

  var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
    .data(pie(data), key);

  function midAngle(d) {
    return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
  }

  text.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.label;
    }).merge(text)
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        var d2 = interpolate(t);
        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
        pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
        return "translate(" + pos + ")";
      };
    })
    .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        var d2 = interpolate(t);
        return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
      };
    });

  text.exit()
    .remove();

  /* ------- SLICE TO TEXT POLYLINES -------*/

  var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
    .data(pie(data), key);

  polyline.enter()
    .append("polyline")
    .merge(polyline)
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("points", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        var d2 = interpolate(t);
        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
        pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
        return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
      };
    });

  polyline.exit()
    .remove();
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

path.slice {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

polyline {
  opacity: .3;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button>Randomize</button>
```